# How can I extract the contents of the <body> tag?

Tags: python

What would be good way of extracting the contents of a `body` tag from an HTML page without relying on Lxml or BeautifulSoup?

I'm writing a add on package for Django and for such a small task, I'd hate to add another dependency to my addon. It would be really easy using one of the libraries that I mentioned but other than that and regexs, I can't think of another method.

Comment: Python comes with a [basic HTML parser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html).

Comment: Huh. I don't know how I missed that one. It looks like a better method than using string functions.

Comment: @katrielalex, would you be willing to provide an example of how this could be accomplished with the `HTMLParser` module? I tried the docs but was quite lost.

Comment: I'll try to write you one -- but honestly, I would just use BeautifulSoup. It can use `HTMLParser` under the covers (so you don't need lxml) and it's a lot more resilient to the kinds of HTML you see "in the wild".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty hacky and I'm sure completely brittle (doesn't account for `<body>` appearing inside of the actual `<body>` tag, etc.), but if you absolutely can't use the above-mentioned libraries, perhaps something like this?

```
In [7]: s = '<html><head>More stuff</head><body>Text inside of the body</body>Random text</html>'

In [8]: s.split('<body>')[1].split('</body>')[0]
Out[8]: 'Text inside of the body'
```

And if `<body>` tags in the actual body are a concern, this abomination seems to work:

```
In [1]: s = '<html><head>More stuff</head><body>Text inside of the body<body>more sample text</body>and then more text and then another<body> and then another </body> and then end</body>Random text</html>'

In [2]: '</body>'.join('<body>'.join(s.split('<body>')[1:]).split('</body>')[:-1])
Out[2]: 'Text inside of the body<body>more sample text</body>and then more text and then another<body> and then another </body> and then end'
```

Comment: Is it really possible to have more than one body tag?

Comment: @MarkRansom I guess I was thinking if it were included in a code snippet or something similar (I guess those would be escaped though).

Comment: @Mark: part of the problem with parsing HTML is how much malformed HTML there is in the world.

Comment: @katrielalex: extremely good point. In that case you should be prepared for a missing `</body>` too, or spaces in the tag, or ...

Comment: @MarkRansom Yeah - I would definitely default to using basically anything other than this :)